# Backup software for service provider?

Tags: backup

Currently using Vembu's storegrid. Not very happy with the user interface, the reports or nothing. Very hard to get a good grip on how well everything is.

- backing up typical servers such as Windows 2003/2008, multiple Linux flavors, exchange, MS SQL, MySQL etc etc.
- Recently we also have an interest in providing small companies backup of their office machines, so either two different solutions or one that is suitable for both.
- We obviously need both full and incremental backups.
- We do backup to DAS (Direct Attached Storage).

What do you guys use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Commvault, it works great for our MSSQL, Linux and VMWare ESXi boxes and isn't as expensive as the Backup Exec we used to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bacula. There are some nice web interfaces available and it is all opensource. It does take a bit to get up and running but once it is up it is stable.